# Limiting memory usage in Memgraph for queries executed under triggers

Tags: memgraphdb

I have been working with Memgraph for some thime now. I've successfully managed to limit memory usage on regular queries and the overall memory usage of Memgraph.

However, I recently ran into a scenario where I'd like to apply similar limits to queries executed under triggers. Is it possible to limit the execution of queries that are run under triggers in Memgraph? If it is, could anyone please guide me through the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, Memgraph can limit query execution, but there is no support for the limiting queries under triggers. There is an open [issue for this on GitHub](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/440).